# Formatting issues resulting in overlays of text from Pages to Word (either version)

Tags: ms-office, pages, formatting

I've drafted a contract in Pages and exported it to Word for a back and forth redline exchange (track changes). I cannot use pdf as my colleague states that he does not have editing capabilities in Adobe format. When I view the exported document on my display it looks perfectly formatted; however, in the smaller "view" window, it looks as if some of the text is overlaid upon other text. I cannot tell what portions are doing this or where,because when I open the exported Word doc it looks fine and the view window is too small to see clearly and it is not zoomable. I sent to a colleague to ask if it looked as I suspected based on the view, and alas, it does.

If anyone knows how I can fix this (w/out using pdf or redrafting) or knows what is causing it, it would be much appreciated.

I am using a font shared by both (Pages/Word)programs and this occurs whether I export to .doc or .docx.

Comment: I recommend you recreate your text in Word or a Word clone like LibreOffice.  Using Pages to create .doc is often a waste of time because of the compatiblity issues.

Comment: I realize I do have that option, but doc is time sensitive (and voluminous) so    I figured that if a fix exists it will save me valuable time. Puzzling, is I've drafted other documents that have exported fine. Also, when I purchased this Mac I discussed buying Word since I draft so many documents, but was assured that updates to Pages over the past year have resolved the compatibility issues, so long as (1) I am not copying from Word and pasting into Pages (thereby having the formatting carryover); and (2) use only a font that exists in both programs. No pasting and used New Times Roman.

Comment: The views of Apple's sales folks about the ability of Pages to substitute for Word are unfortunately fantasy for really serious work in business or academia.  You might want to try the forum for Pages experts and see if anyone there can help.   https://discussions.apple.com/community/iwork/pages

Comment: I have and many people either carry your view, or claim to have no issues converting. Looks like i'm retyping after a Word purchase

Comment: LibreOffice is free and may work just as well.  Try just opening your doc with it and see how it goes.  The latest version can even open .pages to some extent I hear.

Comment: OK I will try this.